# How can I prove that if $|x| > |y|$ then $x^2 > y^2$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

How can I prove that if $|x| > |y|$ then $x^2 > y^2$ using proofs such as contradiction, direct proof.

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your proof to verify, given your tag? What is your definition for $|\cdot|$?

Comment: what kind of numbers are $$x,y$$?

Comment: As remarked above, you should specify the domain of the numbers in the question: in particular, are they real numbers or complex numbers? One benefit of showing some work of your own is that it may give us a clue to what numbers you mean even if you don't know there was even a question about what you meant.

Answer (score 3):

$|x| < |y| \implies |x||x| = |x|^2 = x^2 < |x||y| < |y||y| = |y|^2 = y^2$

Answer (score 2):

Faster, if you assume that $t \mapsto t^2$ is strictly growing on $[0 , \infty)$, then $x^2 < y^2$ if $|x| < |y|$.

Answer (score 0):

Direct Proof. Assume that $|x|>|y|$. Then
$$x^2=|x^2|=|xx|=|x|\cdot|x|>|y|\cdot|y|=|y|^2=|y^2|=y^2.$$